# PG-promise : Query formatting issue in QueryFile

Tags: postgresql, pg-promise

I have a normal sql insert statement where i am trying to insert UUID value. I am using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) named parameters passed with object. I have been struggling with this error for hours. What is the problem in the Query format? Here is the below code that i use to execute the query from Queryfile. I'm not sure it also throws the error twice.

*Source code*

```
pgdb.one(postgresMapper.Registry.TransactionRequest.insert,{
        transaction_request_guid: transactionRequestGuid,
        transaction_request_attributes_id: docId.toString(),
      })
        .then((data) => {
          request.app.transaction_id = data.transaction_request_id;
  });
```

Where *postgresMapper.Registry.TransactionRequest.insert* is the `QueryFile`

*Sql*

```
INSERT INTO public.transaction_request (transaction_request_guid,transaction_request_attributes_id,createdon_utc) VALUES(${transaction_request_guid},${transaction_request_attributes_id},CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) RETURNING transaction_request_id
```

*Console error*

> QueryFile { file:
>   "D:\aud-plugin\build\sqls\insert-transaction-request.sql" options:
>   {"debug":true,"minify":true,"compress":false,"noWarnings":false}
>   query: "INSERT INTO public.transaction_request
>   (transaction_request_guid,transaction_reques
>   t_attributes_id,createdon_utc)
>   VALUES(${transaction_request_guid},${transaction_request_attribu
>   tes_id},CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) RETURNING transaction_request_id" }
>   QueryFile { file:
>   "D:\aud-plugin\build\sqls\insert-transaction-request.sql" options:
>   {"debug":true,"minify":true,"compress":false,"noWarnings":false}
>   query: "INSERT INTO public.transaction_request
>   (transaction_request_guid,transaction_reques
>   t_attributes_id,createdon_utc)
>   VALUES(${transaction_request_guid},${transaction_request_attribu
>   tes_id},CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) RETURNING transaction_request_id" }
>   (node:6164) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 4): Ty peError: Invalid query format.
>   (node:6164) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 6): Ty peError: Invalid query format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this discussion](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/issues/393), you were using more than one version of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) at the same time.

You created `QueryFile` objects using one version of the library, and then tried to use those with a different version. And as `QueryFile` is an internal type, which changed its behavior between versions, thus creating the conflict on your side.

Comment: Thanks for linking it up!